# javascript choose attribute value contains sth

Tags: javascript

First time access the Javascript, it looks like:

please find https://xueqiu.com/v4/statuses/user_timeline.json?page=1&user_id=4357540281

```
{ count: 20
, statuses: 
  [ { id            : 180
    , user_id       : 435
    , source        : '111'
    , title         : 'aa'
    , created_at    : 1621
    , retweet_count : 0
    , reply_count   : 1
    , Timebefore    : '05-20 5-15 8:00'
...
      id            : 181
    , user_id       : 436
    , source        : '111'
    , title         : 'bb'
    , created_at    : 1621
    , retweet_count : 0
    , reply_count   : 1
    , Timebefore    : '05-19 5-15 8:00'
```

I only want to choose value under the condition: Timebefore contains value:'5 -20'.And no idea why could I achieve attribute selection. In selenium, I can try like text contains sth, here I wanna it retuns timebefore contains s specific date. I tried:

```
with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
    _ = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com")
    user_timeline = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com/v4/statuses/user_timeline.json?page=1&user_id=4357540281").json()
    for status in user_timeline["statuses"]:
    status["TimeBefore": '05-20']
```

but it retuns: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that cannot answer the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best was to solve this is to walk the keys and values.  This allows you to look at the structure of your JSON.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
    _ = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com")
    user_timeline = connection.get("https://xueqiu.com/v4/statuses/user_timeline.json?page=1&user_id=4357540281").json()
    for status in user_timeline['statuses']:
        date_string = str(status['timeBefore']).split(" ")[0]
        if '05-20' in date_string:
           print(date_string)
           # output
           05-20
           05-20
           05-20
           truncated...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but still no idea how to choose value, as the website has not been updated today, value```today``` cannot be seen yet, but this could be transferred to how to choose value only contains 5-20, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your response?

Comment: I only want the code returns news issue on 5-20, so I do not know how to achieve that, like in selenium I can use text contains sth, here I wanna use timebefore contains 05-20

Comment: You split the datetime string based on the empty space.  Look at the update in my answer.

Comment: thanks it still returns all the results in the website, I only want like ```a = str(status['timeBefore':'05-20']).split(" ")[0]```, the dates equals 05-20

Comment: You can do that with a str in function.  Look at the updated answer.

Comment: got it, thank you for your help! I think it works

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept the answer.  Thanks.